# Tkinter readonly Combobox listener

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to have a dropdown menu in Tkinter that has a listener (Heavy java programmer here) and I can't find anything that works.

My dropdown menu is readonly, so the user doesn't type their own stuff in. I want to know when the user has finished selecting their item. (So they click on the box to open it up, then I want to know when they choose an element). Binding doesn't work as it only captures when it opens, and my google-fu hasn't got me anywhere after about 2 hours of searching.

I really need this to work as having a button with my multiple comboboxes is going to be a big hindrance to using this (as its supposed to automate stuff).

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Python 3.2/3.3 (not sure which version I will finalize on yet)

Here's some code I have, don't think it will be useful though:

```
presetSettings = ttk.Combobox(mainframe,values=('Custom','Standard', 'LXXL'),state='readonly')
presetSettings.bind('<Button-1>', self.populateTree)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to know when user selects anything from combobox you should bind to virtual combobox event:

```
presetSettings.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", cmbSelected)
```

`cmbSelected` is called only after a user chooses combobox element

Comment: Is there a list of virtual events like this I can find? I looked all over the doc pages for combobox and never saw this. This looks like it should work. Edit: Apparently I didn't read hard enough... it's right there on the normal docs. I literally spent like 2 hours trying to get it work. Thanks!

Comment: Some info can be found at TkDocs - http://www.tkdocs.com/widgets/combobox.html. I found info above mentioned event there.